# You Won't Find 13

Tags: riddle, word

I am playing riddle games in my phone and i stuck on a riddle. The riddle is:

```
If you look at my face you won't find
thirteen  any place.
```

What is the solution to the riddle?

**Hint 1:**

> It is a 5 letter word

**Hint 2:**

> it consist of following letters: XKXVOLWCICUYBW

Comment: It is not a cloak.

Comment: But is it the answer Napoleon and I gave?

Comment: Watch also has 5 letters, but I guess a watch has 13 minutes and 13 seconds...

Comment: If you have to give 2 hints within 6 minutes of posting your riddle, you're doing something wrong...

Comment: @lolgast Is it really true

Comment: You mean CLOCK not CLOAK, don't you?

Comment: I added hints because it can be to broad to answet

Comment: The hints also make us believe it is "clock" :(

Comment: If your riddle would be too broad without them, the "hints" should be part of the riddle. In addition, your second hint doesn't really help - perhaps it's a translation issue, but "to consist of" means that [whatever follows] is part of the answer. Possibly you mean "The answer should be created by selecting 5 of these letters"?

Comment: @rudra Also, all indications are towards the answers given being correct, however your first comment is somewhat weird. Can you confirm the given answers to be incorrect?

Comment: Reminds me of [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q46hYTCb0Ek) from Batman Forever. (warning: the video contains the answer)

Comment: If you plug those letters into an anagram solver, it's very clear whether or not the proposed solutions are correct. I'm not saying they are or aren't, but there's definitely a way of checking out there.

Comment: There is no indication in the puzzle that any numbers at all can be found.

Comment: @Apep - that was my first thought also..

Answer (score 11):

This can be too broad. My first idea is:

> A clock. It only has numbers 1-12.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @ABcDexter for putting the list of possible words together.

This might be a bit of a stretch but...

> Lucky.

"If you look at my face you won't find"

> Luck is often personified as a lady, who would obviously have a face.

"thirteen  any place."

> In the west 13 is considered an unlucky number. Though I admit this might be flawed because 13 is considered lucky in China.

Comment: I suppose this works, but isn't there a much more obvious answer?

Comment: He's already stated clock isn't the answer. Plus it's been guessed, twice. Had to try something different.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is a

> clock

That is because

> a clock has only 1-12 on it’s face

Comment: But has thirteen minutes and thirteen seconds.

Comment: @D.Mellow the numbers we see are 1 to 12. That’s on an analog clock.

Comment: Guess that when he says "any place" he negates the possibility to be a clock...

Comment: But the term "face" is often used to refer to the part on the clock with all the numbers, so I think clock makes sense

Answer (score 4):

All possible words out of these are:

> block
> blowy
> bolix
> bulky
> click
> **clock**
> cluck
> cocky
> colic
> **cubic**
> lucky
> oculi
> xylic

---

We have 13 words. Of these,

> CLOCK fits the description.
>  Cubic can also fit.

---

Try it out in the app.

Answer (score 2):

> Sounds like a clock.

because

> clocks have faces and 13 in them